# How to open a link to a message in Mattermost when the default browser insists in opening the web app?

Tags: slack

I use the messaging app Mattermost for work on my Linux machine. It's common to refer to specific messages using links, which are like URLs and can be opened by a browser. Depending on the browser and configuration, it will either open it the web app or the desktop app of Mattermost.

My default browser Vivaldi opens the web app instead of the desktop app when I click the links. I want the browser to open the desktop app, but didn't find a way to configure that, even after researching on the internet. How can I do it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Mattermost allows you to send direct messages to yourself. When you send yourself a direct message with a link to another message on the desktop app, it will allow you to do what you want and open the message on the desktop app itself.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).